# Auto-populate forms from MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm trying to create a form where you can insert users and also edit users. By default the form is set to add users (`include 'insertuserform.php';`). Underneath the form the table is printed[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWiYU.png)] with an option to edit the user (by linking `index.php?uid=".$row['uid']."&cmd=edit`), where an if statement says that if uid is set and cmd is set to *edit* then it displays the edit user form (`include 'edituserform.php';`) (else display add user form).

To select the department for the user there is a dropdown menu in the add user form which displays the department name, but saves the department ID and the two tables are linked[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxWp4.png)].

When using the edit user form I'm trying to populate the fields automatically with the current data. To do so I'm using a query `SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid={$_GET['uid']}` and then echoing the form with `value='".$row['name']."` inside the input tag (obviously changing name depending on what field).

How do I do something similar for the departments dropdown menu? I've tried `autofocus='".$row['departmentid']."'` but it just sets it to the first option for all users.

I'm sorry if this makes no sense, and I can supply more info if needed.

**tl;dr How do I automatically assign a value to a dropdown select field from a MySQL database?**

[image: Users Table]
[image: Departments Table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add this to your option, if you want it to be autoselected: selected="selected"

For instance:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
  echo "<option value=".$item["departmentid"]." ".($row["departmentid"] == $item["departmentid"] ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "").">".$item["departmentname"]."</option>";
}
```

We suppose "$items" is the result of "select * from departments".

Comment: He is using arrays instead of objects. Might wanna modify your code.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a check in every  element in your .

Try this:

```
<option value="<?= $department['departmentid']; ?>" <?php if($row['departmentid'] == $department['departmentid']) { echo " selected" } ?>><?= $department['departmentname']; ?></option>
```